# Convert foreach in a single query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq Query and a for loop inside it like:

```
double total = 0;

IEnumerable<Dispatch> requiredDispatches = Dispatches.Where(x => x.OrderId == SelectedOrder.OrderId);
foreach(Dispatch dispatch in requiredDispatches)
{
    total += dispatch.DispatchItemTransactions.Sum(x => x.Quantity);
}
```

I have tried it but half only:

```
total = Dispatches.Where(x => x.OrderId == SelectedOrder.OrderId)
                  .Select(x => x.DispatchItemTransactions).Sum( x => x.
```

But after `x.`it does not give me my Property `Quantity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to flatten the hierarchy first, use `SelectMany` and they look for `Sum`

```
var total = Dispatches.Where(x => x.OrderId == SelectedOrder.OrderId)
                      .SelectMany(x => x.DispatchItemTransactions)
                      .Sum( x =>x.Quantity);
```